# Django use 'python manage.py' runserver instead Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, django-manage.py

I have a django project hosted on an amazon ec2 linux instance.
For run my app also when section is close i use gunicorn but i experience some errors and degradation in perfonrmances.
When i run command:

> python manage.py runserver

from terminal all works great but when section is close app does not work.

How can i run command "python manage.py runserver" for work forever (until i'll kill it) in background also in case of closed session?

I know there is uWSGI but i prefer if possible use directly django native command.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't do this. The [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver) are very specific about `manage.py runsverver`: **DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING**

Answer (score 4):

What happens here is that the script is interrupted by `SIGHUP` signal when your session is closed.  To overcome this problem, there is a tool called `nohup` which doesn't pass the `SIGHUP` down to the program/script it executes.  Use it as follows:

```
nohup python manage.py runserver &
```

(note the `&` in the end, it is needed so that `manage.py` runs in background rather than in foreground).

By default `nohup` redirects the output in the file `nohup.out`, so you can use `tail -f nohup.out` to watch the output/logs of your Django app.

Note, however, that `manage.py runserver` is **not supposed to be used in production**. For production you really should use a proper WSGI server, such as uWSGI or Gunicorn.

Answer (score 2):

You can install and use ***tmux*** if you want to run your scripts in background even after closing **SSH** and **mosh** connections

```
$ sudo apt-get install tmux
```

then run it using command `$ tmux` a new shell will be opened just execute your command

$ `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

**0.0.0.0:8000** here will automatically get your allowed hosts. Now you can detach your tmux session to run it in background using **CTRL + B** and then press **D**

Now you can exit your terminal but your command keep on running in tmux. Just learn basic commands to use tmux from [here](https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/)

Answer (score 0):

for that, you can use screen just start a new screen and run
`python manage.py runserver`